# MongoDB Ops manager backup issue

Tags: mongodb

I want to deploy backup features using mongodb ops manager version 1,8. I have already installed ops manager and it's running but while i am clicking on backup tab it's showing below message. Please suggest how can i fix it.

"Backup is an optional module, which has not been configured for Ops Manager your installation"

Answer (score 1):

In the version 1.8, the backup was optional as [the documentation](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/v1.8/core/system-overview/) says. That version is quite old, the current version is 3.4 where [backup is included](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/system-overview/) to ops manager package.